# Is there any way to find out unused locators in selenium project?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have a huge selenium project which we update on a day to day basis. Sometimes we miss to remove locators which are no longer in use. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Most IDE providing this feature.
For example PyCharm IDE indicates unused stuff as following:

[image]

IntelliJ IDE provides the following usage indications:

[image]

I believe all the modern IDE tools providing such indications.